# How to overlay a TikZ picture on a TikZ picture generated by a macro?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a beginner in LaTeX, tentatively using it for industrial documents. I am facing a lot of trouble trying to add some simple Tikz graphics to a series of Tikz pictures (very complicated, with lots of code and numerous arguments in each) generated by a series of macros. I would like to add to them additional notes with arrows, and occasionnaly, include the combined resulting graphics into figures with captions. It seemed to me that the "remember picture, overlay" option would do the job. Below is an overly simplified example. However I cannot understand how the coordinate system of the second picture relates to the first picture. I have tentatively tried to add "remember picture, overlay" to the macro generating the first picture, but without improvements... Could someone explain, and advise a path forward?

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{wired}=[draw=gray!30, line width=0.15mm]
\tikzstyle{number}=[anchor=center, color=white]
\newcommand{\strip}[4]{
    \filldraw[#1, wired]
      ({18 *  #2}      :                   #3) arc
      ({18 *  #2}      : {18 * (#2 + 1)} : #3) --
      ({18 * (#2 + 1)} :                   #4) arc
      ({18 * (#2 + 1)} : {18 *  #2}      : #4) -- cycle;
}
\newcommand{\sector}[3]{
    \filldraw[#1, wired]
      (0, 0) --
      ({18 * #2} :                   #3) arc
      ({18 * #2} : {18 * (#2 + 1)} : #3) -- cycle;
}
\newcommand{\DrawShape}[0]{%
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=81, scale=.2, remember picture, overlay]
  \fill[gray!50] (0, 0) circle (225.5mm);
  \foreach\i in {1,3,...,19} {
    \sector{white}{\i}{162mm}
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
}%
\begin{document}

\DrawShape

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8]
\begin{scope}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (n1) at (0, 0);
\node[draw,font=\small,inner sep=5pt, anchor=west] (n1x) at (0.6,0) {\textbf{Optimum location}}; 
\draw[<-, >=latex,line width =5 pt, red] (n1) -- (n1x.west);
\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [draw] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{10cm}
\DrawShape

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8]
\begin{scope}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (n1) at (0, 0);
\node[draw,font=\small,inner sep=5pt, anchor=west] (n1x) at (0.6,0) {\textbf{Optimum location}}; 
\draw[<-, >=latex,line width =5 pt, red] (n1) -- (n1x.west);
\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [draw] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{An embarassing shift of the coordinate system and caption position \dots}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not that easy to understand your code, so I made this from scratch. Is this what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\newcommand{\bullseye}[1]%
{   \begin{scope}[shift=(#1)]
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \fill[even odd rule,gray!50] (0,0) circle (4)
            \foreach \x in {1,...,18}
            {   (0,0) -- (\x*20:3) -- (\x*20+10:3) -- (0,0)
            };
        \end{pgfonlayer}        
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[remember picture] (myorigin) at (0,0);
\draw (0,0) grid ++(5,5);
\bullseye{myorigin}
\draw[ultra thick,red,<-] (myorigin) -- ++ (2,1) node[right] {Bullseye's center};
\end{tikzpicture}

This is a Test.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[remember picture] (myorigin) at (1,2);
\bullseye{myorigin}
\draw (0,0) grid ++(5,5);
\draw[ultra thick,red,<-] (myorigin) -- ++ (2,1) node[right] {Bullseye's center};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** Of course, you can use it inside a figure environment. The trick is to first specify where the bullseye should be and then draw the circle. Normally you would have to first draw the circle and then everything else, otherwise the circle would paint over your picture. To avoid this, you can specify layers (in this case three: background, main and foreground). Then you can draw pictures on them and TikZ will stack them for you according to the layer they are on.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\newcommand{\bullseye}[1]%
{   \begin{scope}[shift=(#1)]
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \fill[even odd rule,gray!50] (0,0) circle (4)
            \foreach \x in {1,...,18}
            {   (0,0) -- (\x*20:3) -- (\x*20+10:3) -- (0,0)
            };
        \end{pgfonlayer}        
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[hb]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
            \coordinate[remember picture] (myorigin) at (0,0);
            \draw (0,0) grid ++(5,5);
            \bullseye{myorigin}
            \draw[ultra thick,red,<-] (myorigin) -- ++ (2,1) node[right] {Bullseye's center};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\caption{This is the first picture}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[hb]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
            \coordinate[remember picture] (myorigin) at (1,2);
            \draw (0,0) grid ++(5,5);
            \bullseye{myorigin}
            \draw[ultra thick,red,<-] (myorigin) -- ++ (2,1) node[right] {Bullseye's center};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\caption{This is the second picture}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The result is what I am looking for...Apologies for the code. As mine was far too long and far more complicated,  I had borrowed it and stripped it from a lot of features....and possibly from the original design intent...What is the main trick?  Is it the addition of the \pgfdeclarelayer lines? I am not familiar with this.  Or is it the clear identification of the origin in \coordinate[remember picture] (myorigin) at (0,0)? Would it be possible to enclose it into a \begin{figure} \end{figure} with caption?

Comment: I have seen that you have removed from the macro the Tikz picture environment, keeping only inner code. I was trying tu use a standalone macro drawing the first tikz picture on its own. Perhaps this is not possible...

Comment: Is the overlay option much different than the one specifying the layers ? In my case, the arrow is place on top of hte first picture, as desired, but this is the coordinate system that does not match or worse, seems to change accordig to rules that are very difficult to understand.

Comment: One problem with overlay is that it won't be used for computing the bounding box of the picture, so it may overlap with previousely drawn things like text.

Comment: @Yves: I am curious, what is the "rubik's grid" for?

Answer (score 3):

Another approach consists of 3 steps:

1. By using `standalone` document class or `preview` package, compile the original (La)TeX input files (that contain the existing Ti*k*Z macros without your additional codes) to produce PDF images.
2. Create a new (La)TeX input file for each PDF image to overlay notes (for example) on the image. You can use either PSTricks or Ti*k*Z to do this job. In this answer I will use PSTricks for the sake of "simplicity". Compiling the input file, you will get another PDF image with your notes (for example).
3. From within your main (La)TeX input file, you import the overlaid PDF image using `\includegraphics`. You can also apply some "accessories" (such as `\caption`, `\centering`, `\label`, etc) to it.

The advantages of this approach:

1. You don't need to understand the existing Ti*k*Z macros in the original (La)TeX input files.
2. The input files (either the original ones or the overlaying ones) become neater, cleaner, and more readable.
3. Compilation becomes faster.

Let's do the steps one by one.

### Step 1

Assume that your original (La)TeX input file is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{wired}=[draw=gray!30, line width=0.15mm]
\tikzstyle{number}=[anchor=center, color=white]

\newcommand{\sector}[3]{
    \filldraw[#1, wired]
      (0, 0) --
      ({18 * #2} :                   #3) arc
      ({18 * #2} : {18 * (#2 + 1)} : #3) -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=81, scale=.2]
  \fill[gray!50] (0, 0) circle (225.5mm);
  \foreach\i in {1,3,...,19}{\sector{white}{\i}{162mm}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you compile it with `pdflatex` (or `xelatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`), you will get a PDF image but with unwanted white space around it. To remove the unwanted white space, replace `\documentclass{article}` with `\documentclass[border=<length>]{standalone}` where `length` must be replaced with `0pt` (for example) or any values you like.

The following is the modified code.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{wired}=[draw=gray!30, line width=0.15mm]
\tikzstyle{number}=[anchor=center, color=white]

\newcommand{\sector}[3]{
    \filldraw[#1, wired]
      (0, 0) --
      ({18 * #2} :                   #3) arc
      ({18 * #2} : {18 * (#2 + 1)} : #3) -- cycle;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=81, scale=.2]
  \fill[gray!50] (0, 0) circle (225.5mm);
  \foreach\i in {1,3,...,19}{\sector{white}{\i}{162mm}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Recompiling it again, you will get a PDF output as follows:

[image]

Let us name this PDF output as `tightOriginal.pdf`.

### Step 2

Now we will overlay some notes on `tightOriginal.pdf`. For the sake of "simplicity" I will use PSTricks rather than Ti*k*Z.

The navigation grid should be turned on by setting `showgrid=top` during the development.

[image]

Later you can turn it off by setting `showgrid=false`. You can also set `border=0pt` to get a tight PDF output.

[image]

The input file is as follows, make sure that you compile it with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}

\def\Rows{5}
\def\Columns{5}
\def\Scale{0.9}
\def\Filename{tightOriginal}
\def\SetLabel#1{\color{blue}\bf\Large#1}


\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[width=\Scale\linewidth]{\Filename}}


\newpsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    subgriddots=15,
    subgridcolor=green,
    griddots=15,
    gridcolor=red,
}

\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\Rows\relax,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\Columns\relax,
    nodesepA=3pt,
    linecolor=red,
    linewidth=3pt,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox)
\rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
% Axis
\psComment[ref=Cl,angleA=180]{->}(4,4.6)(0.5\wd\IBox,0.5\ht\IBox){\SetLabel{Axis}}[\ncdiagg]
% Spoke
\psComment[ref=Cr]{->}(1,4.6)(2,3.2){\SetLabel{Spoke}}[\ncdiagg]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Let us name the PDF output as `overlaid.pdf`

### Step 3

The last step is to import `overlaid.pdf` from our main input file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{overlaid}
\caption{My wheel of fortune.}
\label{fig:wheel}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Compile it with `pdflatex` and  we will get an output as follows:

[image]

Comment: Very interesting solution. And very clear, educational path. Thanks.